# Best way to implement oauth consumer in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

What is best way to implement oauth consumer in cakephp. Should I write plugin based on [oauth.php](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php) or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're going to use OAuth for, but it'll probably be integrated in the application you're developing, so writing a plugin might be the least desirable way to tackle the problem.

There's [a third-party Vendor/Component package](http://code.42dh.com/oauth) by cakebaker for Cake, unfortunately it only supports 1.2/1.3 and the [2.0 branch](https://github.com/cakebaker/oauth-consumer-component/tree/cakephp_2.0) isn't actively worked on at the moment, so it seems. No information on how well it will integrate with the current stable version of Cake.

CakeDC also hosts [an OAuth library](https://github.com/CakeDC/oauth_lib) which might contain the functionality you're looking for. There's also [a 2.0 branch](https://github.com/CakeDC/oauth_lib/tree/2.0) which is actively maintained.

Comment: CakeDC has an OAuth consumer implementation, but if you want a single purpose library for Cake you might have to roll your own.